# VSCode - keybinding cannot bind my shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, document

I set Ctrl+Alt+l to format document in VSCode. It used to work but after a while of being inactive I tried to use it again with no success.

When I press the shortcut it produces a Polish letter "ł" (for which the shortcut in Windows10 is right Alt+l).

The shortcut is established in VSCode though. It says Format Document - Keybinding Ctrl + Alt + L. The shortcut isn't doubling.

Formatting document works if I use it from straight from VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

So, your system's keybinding is probably having a preference over that keybind. Can't you remove that keyboard shortcut from your system, or change your keyboard language if you don't use those polish keys?

Comment: I guess I could change keyoboard language but that would not be the ultimate solution to my problem then.. PS This used to work before.

Comment: Magically, it started to work now. Just changed Format.Document to Ctrl+ALt+L . May be due to the fact that I'm working in React now, not in JavaScript.